# Using std::bind in Variadic Template Classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm attempting to build a simple class to wrap around functions and call (possibly return) them without passing any values except during constructing the class. The problem with this, however, is that I can't seem to reach the level of ambiguity necessary. The sample code I have is as follows:

```
template< typename T, typename... Arguments>
struct FunctionPtrWrapper
{
    FunctionPtrWrapper(T(*funcIn)(Arguments...), Arguments... args)
    {
        funcPtr=std::bind(funcIn, args...);
    }
    void go()
    {
        funcPtr();
    }
    std::function< T(Arguments...)> funcPtr;
};
```

It compiles fine and even runs when passed functions without arguments, but when passing a function that requires arguments, it will fail to compile if go() is called, so that:

```
FuctionPtrWrapper<void> pointerOne(&foo);
pointerOne.go();
```

works perfectly, but:

```
FunctionPtrWrapper<void, char> pointerTwo(&foo, 'c');
pointerTwo.go();
```

Fails to compile with the following error:

`error: no match for call to '(std::function< void(char)>) ()`

Which I assume means that somehow in the constructor, the argument fails to expand and pass to the call to std::bind. Is this a syntactical error, misuse of the used functions or simply not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your `std::bind` call bound all the parameters, so the function object returned by it should be invoked without a parameter.

Thus, the `std::function`'s type parameter should always be `T()`, not `T(Arguments...)`:

```
std::function<T()> funcPtr;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6518ee8b869515d).